# Conditional expectation $\operatorname E[\varepsilon_s\varepsilon_t\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}]$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, conditional-expectation, time-series

Suppose that $\{X_t\}_{t\in\mathbb Z}$ is an AR($1$) process given by
$$
X_t=\mu+\phi X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t
$$
for $t\in\mathbb Z$, where $\mu\in\mathbb R$, $|\phi|<1$ and $\{\varepsilon_t\}_{t\in\mathbb Z}$ are iid random variables such that $\operatorname E\varepsilon_0=0$ and $\operatorname E\varepsilon_0^2=\sigma^2<\infty$. I am trying to evaluate the conditional expectation
$$
\operatorname E[\varepsilon_s\varepsilon_t\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}]
$$
with $s,t=2,\ldots,n-1$.

> Since $\varepsilon_s=X_s-\mu-\phi X_{s-1}$ and $\varepsilon_t=X_t-\mu-\phi X_{t-1}$ for $s,t=2,\ldots,n-1$, the random variables $\varepsilon_s$ and $\varepsilon_t$ with $s,t=2,\ldots,n-1$ should be measurable with respect to the sigma algebra generated by $X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}$. Hence,
>   $$
> \operatorname E[\varepsilon_s\varepsilon_t\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}]=\varepsilon_s\varepsilon_t
> $$
>   for $s,t=2,\ldots,n-1$. Is this correct?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes that should be correct. It's usually called the 'pulling out what is known' property of conditional expectation.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties